# Closure of the non-negative combinations of a collection of vectors

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Given $a_1,\ldots,a_n \in \mathbb{R}^d$, is the set $\{c_1 a_1+\cdots+c_na_n, \text{ where } c_i \geq 0 \text{ for all } i\}$  closed in $ \mathbb{R}^d$?

Comment: What are your thoughts? How would you go about showing it is or isn't closed?

Comment: It's definitely true when n=1. I was wondering what happens generally when $n>1$. Intuitively, it should be true. How about a proof or counterexample?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16738/topology-proof-that-a-finitely-generated-cone-is-closed

Comment: You try to do this by using that a set in $\mathbb R^d$ is closed if and only if for every convergent sequence entirely contained in the set, the limit of the sequence is also contained in the set.

Comment: I was wondering if there is a simple proof along the direction suggested above. Even better, is there an inductive argument, given that it IS true when n=1.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Without loss of generality we can assume that the set $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ is minimal in the sense that no $a_i$ is a positive linear combination of the others. Moreover we can assume that $a_1,a_2,...,a_k$, $k\leq n$, is a maximal subset of $\{a_1,a_2,...,a_n\}$ that is linearly independent.

Let $b_1=a_1,b_2=a_2,...,b_k=a_k,b_{k+1},...,b_d$ be a basis of $\mathbb{R}^d$.

If $a$ is a point outside of that cone, then either a coordinate of $a$ along one $a_i$, $1\leq i\leq k$ is negative or a coordinate along one $b_i$, $i>k$ is non-zero. But this implies that the same is true for all points in a small enough neighborhood of $a$. Since those conditions imply a point is not in the cone, then all points in the small ball are not in the cone. This proves the complement of the cone is open.